# How to simplify a script

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

Im still quite new to coding. However using Stack Overflow and my own basic knowledge I have created a script that allows a postcode to be searched from a database and display the radius results. Part of the code also allows for a town to be searched also. However the town is in another database which cant be moved. So the coded below i would like to simplify as it looks over complicated. Can anyone help? Also, while it is searching the database. I would like to add something like the words Searching while it is doing it.

```
    <?php

$postcode = str_replace( '+', '%20', $postcode );
$postcode = str_replace( '!"£$^&*()?<>', '', $postcode );

include ('config.php');

$sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM postcodelatlng WHERE postcode LIKE '".$postcode." %' OR postcode = '".$postcode."' ";
$result = mysql_query($sqlstring);   

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$lng = $row["longitude"] / 180 * M_PI;
$lat = $row["latitude"] / 180 * M_PI;

mysql_free_result($result);    

$sqlstring2 = "SELECT DISTINCT 
  postcodelatlng.postcode,
  (
    6367.41 * SQRT(
      2 * (
        1- COS(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.latitude)) * COS(".$lat.") * (
          SIN(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.longitude)) * SIN(".$lng.") + COS(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.longitude)) * COS(".$lng.")
        ) - SIN(RADIANS(postcodelatlng.latitude)) * SIN(".$lat.")
      )
    )
  ) AS Distance 
FROM
  postcodelatlng AS postcodelatlng 
HAVING Distance <= '".$radius."'
ORDER BY Distance ";

$i = 1;

$result1 = mysql_query($sqlstring2) or die('query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        $searchlets = "SELECT * FROM property_details WHERE postcode = '".$row['postcode']."' ";
                $getresult = mysql_query($searchlets);
                    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($getresult)) {

                        echo '  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="viewprop.php?id='.$row2[0].'" target="_blank">
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 innerResults col-xs-12" align="justify">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/rentals/1.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                            <h3 class="rbgclr1" style="text-align:left;">'. $row2[13]. '</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="rbgclr1" style="text-align:left;">'. $row2[9]. '</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <h4 class="rbgclr2">£'. $row2[2]. ' Per Month</h3>
                            <h5 class="rbgclr1">£'. $row2[3]. ' Deposit</h4>
                            <br />
                            <p class="rbgclr1">Bedrooms = '. $row2[4]. '</p>
                            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="viewprop.php?id='.$row2[0].'" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <br />';
            if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 0)
   echo '<hr/>';
                    }


    }


$searchlets2 = "SELECT * FROM property_details WHERE street = '".$postcode."' ";
                $getresult2 = mysql_query($searchlets2);
                    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($getresult2)) {
                        echo '  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <a href="viewprop.php?id='.$row3[0].'">
                <div class="col-md-12"> 
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-0 innerResults col-xs-12" align="justify">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/rentals/1.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                            <h3 class="rbgclr1" style="text-align:left;">'. $row3[13]. '</h3>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="rbgclr1" style="text-align:left;">'. $row3[9]. '</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                            <h4 class="rbgclr2">£'. $row3[2]. ' Per Month</h3>
                            <h5 class="rbgclr1">£'. $row3[3]. ' Deposit</h4>
                            <br />
                            <p class="rbgclr1">Bedrooms = '. $row3[4]. '</p>
                            <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="viewprop.php?id='.$row3[0].'" data-layout="button_count" data-mobile-iframe="true"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
            <br />';
            if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 0)
   echo '<hr/>';
                    }

mysqli_close($con); 

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you not to use names like $result1 and $result2. That's unclear. Also, mysql is deprecated and try to separate your code from your view.

Comment: Ok, changed that now.

Comment: I would suggest to use some MVC framework (basically split HTML code and PHP code) and try to learn some of the javascript and AJAX. Otherwise there's no way how to write a searching on the page and display the result when the search is done.

Answer (score 0):

```
    postcode LIKE '".$postcode." %'
 OR postcode  =   '".$postcode."'
```

can be simplified (and sped up) by doing simply

```
    postcode LIKE '".$postcode." %'
```

You will need

```
INDEX(postcode)
```

(I'm not going to wade through the HTML code; this is the wrong forum for that.  Please simplify the code to mostly SQL.)

The `distance` formula needs to scan through the entire table.  Whether that is fast enough depends on how big that table is.

You can fetch data from to different databases (on the same saver) with syntax like

```
FROM db1.tableA JOIN db2.tableB ON ...
```

Use `JOIN` instead of fetching from one table, then another.

Do *not* use the `mysql_*` interface; it is deprecated and will vanish soon.  Switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.  Do *not* mix them!  (I see `mysqli_close` at the end.)

Clean up those things, then start the question over.